# Configure OpenLDAP with TLS=required

Tags: ldap, openldap, tls

Nowadays, OpenLDAP needs to be configured with ldapmodify cn=config, as describe [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/openldap-server.html). But nowhere I can find how you configure it to *only* accept TLS traffic. I just confirmed that our server accepts unencrypted traffic (with ldapsearch and tcpdump).

Normally, I would just close the non-SSL port with IP tables, but using the SSL port is deprecated, apparently, so I don't have that option.

So, with the SSL configuration commands, like this:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype:modify
replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/bla.key
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/bla.crt
-
replace: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/ca.pem
```

Is there a param for forcing TLS?

Edit: I tried the olcTLSCipherSuite, but it doesn't work. Debug output:

```
TLS: could not set cipher list TLSv1+RSA:!NULL.
main: TLS init def ctx failed: -1
slapd destroy: freeing system resources.
slapd stopped.
connections_destroy: nothing to destroy.
```

Edit2 (almost fixed): I was able to fix it by loading:

```
# cat force-ssl.tx 
dn: cn=config
changetype:  modify
add: olcSecurity
olcSecurity: tls=1
```

But then commands like

```
ldapmodify -v -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/ssl/tls-required.ldif
```

Don't work anymore... And changing it to:

```
ldapmodify -v -x -D "cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=com" -H ldap://ldap.bla.tld/ -ZZ -W -f force-ssl.txt
```

gives me "ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)". Apparently, even though this binddn is specified as rootdn, I can't use it to alter `cn=config`. Can that be changed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I seemed to have gotten it:

I  did this:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype:  modify
add: olcSecurity
olcSecurity: tls=1
```

And that seems to have the desired effect. I can still run commands like:

```
ldapsearch -LLL -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=config
```

But trying to bind with "`ldapsearch -xLLL -b ...`" without SSL says: "TLS confidentiality required"

Comment: +1 it seems to work great. Unfortunately if the client tries to authenticate without STARTTLS it sends the password in plaintext, and then the server responds with the `TLS confidentiality required` message.

Comment: I posted that on the OpenLDAP mailing list as a possible security issue. I gave the example of FTP, which blocks as soon as you give USER. But, I was overruled. [See this.](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201212/msg00221.html)

Comment: funny, I looked at that thread before I found this answer :)

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. The password going over the wire in cleartext is going to be implementation specific on the client-side software. TLS requirement can be tested with anonymous bind first before trying to bind as the user.

Comment: Can you explain what makes the difference between your original `dn: cn=config` and now `dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config`? I can't seem to find an explanation anywhere on the web.

Comment: @not2savvy unfortunately I can't. I find it completely arcane. And, with the new version of openldap, which changed significantly, it may not even work anymore?

Comment: I've started [a new question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76099160/4850949).

Answer (score 3):

This is achieved with the [TLSCipherSuite](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/#tlsciphersuite) option.  An example is documented at [LDAP security chapter of the OpenLDAP Zytrax book](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch15/#tls).  With it you can tell OpenLDAP the cipher suites that your server will accept.  For example, you can tell that you don't want a `NULL` cipher suite (ie: non encrypted session).

Be careful though that OpenLDAP can be linked against OpenSSL or GnuTLS libraries.  Those use different cipher lists to describe their encryption support.  The OpenSSL cipher list can be obtained with a command like `openssl ciphers -v` and the GnuTLS list with `gnutls-cli -l`.

The **simplest way to disable connecting without encryption** would then be:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCipherSuite
olcTLSCipherSuite: ALL:!NULL
```

A more specific restriction using **GnuTLS syntax**:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCipherSuite
olcTLSCipherSuite: TLS_RSA_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA1:TLS_RSA_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA1:!NULL
```

A more complete example might be (using **OpenSSL syntax**):

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCipherSuite
olcTLSCipherSuite: HIGH:+SSLv3:+TLSv1:MEDIUM:+SSLv2:@STRENGTH:+SHA:+MD5:!NULL
```

There's an OpenLDAP mailing list discussion worth reading [about a similar question](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200803/msg00199.html).

It's also worth noting that the OpenLDAP cli tools, like `ldapsearch`, are automatically switching to using TLS when connecting to a server forbidding the unencrypted connections.  That means that you do *not* need to add `-Z` to the args list.

Comment: I tried it. It didn't work. I edited my question to reflect it.

Comment: I think the error you report is related to the ciphers your TLS implementation knows about.  OpenLDAP can be compiled with OpenSSL or gnuTLS libraries.  The example I gave used OpenSSL syntax, your implementation is probably using gnuTLS.  I'd suggestion you try a simplified CipherSuite, for example `ALL:!NULL`

Comment: "WARNING: Don’t be clever and change the TLSCipherSuite to something clever like HIGH:MEDIUM:-SSLv2 – this is an openssl directive" - read http://rogermoffatt.com/2011/08/24/ubuntu-openldap-with-ssltls/ .