# Configure OpenLDAP using GnuTLS with TLS=required

Tags: ldap, openldap, starttls, gnutls

We have an openldap server and don't want to allow unencrypted communication, so acceptable is either tls over port 389 (`starttls`) or ssl over 636 (`ldaps`).

As we use slapd.conf for configuration, `olcSecurity` isn't an option.

`TLSCipherSuite` seems to be the way to do it with slapd.conf. But when using that slapd either doesn't start or ignores the settings (i.e. accepts unencrypted requests).

slapd doesn't start (error: TLS init def ctx failed: -1) when using:

```
- TLSCipherSuite ALL
- TLSCipherSuite Default
- TLSCipherSuite ALL:!NULL
- TLSCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL
- TLSCipherSuite AES256-SHA #one of the ciphers offered by openssl
```

slapd starts but accepts unencrypted requests when using:

```
- TLSCipherSuite NORMAL
- TLSCipherSuite NORMAL:!NULL #would be acceptable
- TLSCipherSuite !NULL #would be acceptable
```

We test with

```
ldapsearch -L -x -W -h [SERVER] -D [USER] - b [SEARCHBASE] uid=[USER]
```

(unencrypted)

and

```
ldapsearch -L -x -W -ZZ -h [SERVER] -D [USER] - b [SEARCHBASE] uid=[USER]
```

(encrypted)

The os openldap is running on is debian 8.7. The openldap version seems to be using gnutls, not openssl, so that may be the reason for the problems.

But the last three `TLSCipherSuite` variations seem to be valid syntax, at least slapd starts without errors. Why doesn't `!NULL` prevent slapd from accepting unencrypted requests? The last two (use any cipher available but don't allow no cipher) would be acceptable.

Are additional settings / parameters required?

Note that we tried the suggestions given [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/459718/configure-openldap-with-tls-required) (as described above) but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop using `slapd.conf`, but that's just general advice. Most if not all `olc*` directives from `slapd-config` are available as non-olc directives for a `slapd.conf` style configuration.

For `security` something on the order of `security tls=1` should be sufficient unless you also do non-TLS SASL.

---

Your manipulations of `TLSCipherSuite` will not work because those only control the acceptable ciphers once TLS is in use, it doesn't matter in choosing whether or not to use/require TLS. For that, you'll want to use `security`. However, you should use better TLS options, e.g. at least `TLSCipherSuite HIGH:!aNull:!MD5:@STRENGTH` and `olcTLSProtocolMin 3.1`.

---

From `slapd.conf(5)`:

> **`security <factors>`**
>   Specify  a  set of security strength factors (separated by white space) to require (see **`sasl-secprops's minssf`** option for a description of security strength factors). The directive may be specified globally and/or per-database.  **`ssf=<n>`** specifies the overall security strength factor.  **`transport=<n>`** specifies the transport  security strength  factor.   **`tls=<n>`**  specifies  the TLS security strength factor.  **`sasl=<n>`** specifies the SASL security strength factor.  **`update_ssf=<n>`** specifies the overall security strength factor to require for directory updates. **`update_transport=<n>`** specifies the transport security strength factor to require  for  directory  updates. **`update_tls=<n>`**  specifies  the  TLS security strength factor to require for directory updates. **`update_sasl=<n>`** specifies the SASL security strength factor to require for directory updates. **`simple_bind=<n>`** specifies the security strength factor required for simple username/password authentication.  Note that the  transport  factor is measure of security provided by the underlying transport, e.g. ldapi:// (and eventually IPSEC).  It is not normally used.

Answer (score 0):

If you must continue using slapd.conf, then [this thread](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201202/msg00416.html) holds the answer you need:

> From man slapd.conf
>
> **TLSVerifyClient** `<level>`
>
> `demand | hard | true`
>
> These  keywords  are  all  equivalent,  for compatibility reasons.  The client certificate  is requested.   If  no certificate   is   provided,  or  a  bad certificate  is provided, the session is immediately terminated.

In terms of cipher selection, [Zytrax's LDAP for Rocket Scientists](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/ldap-conf.html) provides some hints:

```
# Cipher-list contains only RSA based
# authentication and key-exchange suites 
# supported by TLSv1 (and SSLv3)
TLS_CIPHER_SUITE TLSv1+RSA

# Cipher-list contains only RSA based
# authentication and key-exchange suites 
# supported by TLSv1 (and SSLv3)
# excludes EXPORT and NULL suites
TLS_CIPHER_SUITE TLSv1+RSA:!EXPORT:!NULL

# Ordered list of RSA based
# authentication and key-exchange suites
TLS_CIPHER_SUITE DES-CBC-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5

# All ciphers excluding NULL
TLS_CIPHER_SUITE ALL:!NULL

# Default equivalent value if not defined
TLS_CIPHER_SUITE ALL
```

You need to change `TLS_CIPHER_SUITE` to `TLSCipherSuite`, and I suspect you might want to check what cipher names will work (from the [admin guide](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/tls.html)):

> Besides the individual cipher names, the specifiers HIGH, MEDIUM, LOW, EXPORT, and EXPORT40 may be helpful, along with TLSv1, SSLv3, and SSLv2.
>
> To obtain the list of ciphers in GnuTLS use:
>
> ```
>    `gnutls-cli -l`
> ```